# Load Test with PhantomJS on Azure throws error when runs with too many users

Tags: azure, selenium, phantomjs, cloud, load-testing

I try to run Load Test with PhantomJS on Azure by guide from Microsoft.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/11/16/using-selenium-with-cloud-based-load-testing/

Test opens page, makes login and stays on the site.

With ~20 users it works well. When I try with 30 and more users, it throws error:

**Initialization method SeleniumWebLoadPoc.SelenumLoadWeb.SetupTest threw exception. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:1341/.**

Code of my test:

```
[TestClass]
public class SelenumLoadWeb
{
    private IWebDriver _driver;
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
    private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
    private string baseURL;
    private bool acceptNextAlert = true;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        _driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
        baseURL = "https://***.com/";
        verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
    }

    [TestMethod]

    [DeploymentItem("SeleniumWebLoadPoc\\OnlyLogin.csv", "SeleniumWebLoadPoc")]
    [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "|DataDirectory|\\SeleniumWebLoadPoc\\OnlyLogin.csv", "OnlyLogin#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]

    public void TheSelenumLoadWebTest()
    {
        var UserName = TestContext.DataRow["UserName"].ToString();
        var PassWord = TestContext.DataRow["Pass"].ToString();

        // OPEN LOGIN PAGE  
        TestContext.BeginTimer("SelenumLoadWeb_Navigate");
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL);
        TestContext.EndTimer("SelenumLoadWeb_Navigate");

        // LOGIN WITH USERNAME AND PASSWORD
        _driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtUName")).Click();
        _driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtUName")).Clear();
        _driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtUName")).SendKeys(UserName);
        _driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtPass")).Click();
        _driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtPass")).Clear();
        _driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtPass")).SendKeys(PassWord);
        TestContext.BeginTimer("SelenumLoadWeb_Login");
        _driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnOkLogin")).Click();
        TestContext.EndTimer("SelenumLoadWeb_Login");
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        try
        {
            _driver.Quit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
        }
        Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
    }
    private bool IsElementPresent(By by)
    {
        try
        {
            _driver.FindElement(by);
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private bool IsAlertPresent()
    {
        try
        {
            _driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoAlertPresentException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private string CloseAlertAndGetItsText()
    {
        try
        {
            IAlert alert = _driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
            string alertText = alert.Text;
            if (acceptNextAlert)
            {
                alert.Accept();
            }
            else
            {
                alert.Dismiss();
            }
            return alertText;
        }
        finally
        {
            acceptNextAlert = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Some one tried to run Load tests with PhantomJS with many users?

Comment: I wouldn't expect more than a few PhantomJS processes can be spawned from a single machine.  30 sounds extremely unrealistic.

Comment: Right, maximum ~25 on one machine